# Como evitar que Excel convierta el texto "true" por verdadero

Tags: excel, vba, csv, macros, booleano

No se si esta pregunta puede estar en este foro pero mi problema es que tengo un archivo csv (separado por comas) el cuál modificó desde una macro en otro libro xlsm el archivo contiene varias columnas pero la macro sólo modifica una sola, el problema es que hay columnas que tienen como valor "true" o "false" pero después de ejecutar la macro, mágicamente se convierten a "VERDADERO" Y "FALSO". la macro ni siquiera guarda el csv, solo lo abre y lo modifica, yo lo guardo de manera manual como csv, pero no entiendo porque me modifica todas las columnas booleanas por "verdadero" o "falso", quisiera saber si hay un modo de evitar que Excel haga eso sin tener que indicar manualmente o por código, las columnas que son solo texto, como repito, en la macro solo modifico una columna, todo lo demás quiero que se quede exactamente como está.

```
Sub actualiza()
Dim wbLista As Workbook
dim wsLista As Excel.Worksheet 

Set wbLista = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\libro.csv")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsLista = wbLista.Worksheets("hoja1")
ThisWorkbook.Activate 'la hoja activa es el source
Dim uf As Integer 'ultima fila
Dim fila As Integer 'fila Lista
fila = 2
Dim f As Integer 'fila source
While wsLista.Range("A" & fila).Value <> "" 'recorro lista
    f = 2
    If wsLista.Range("N" & fila).Value <> "" Then 'comprobacion para no leer registros no validos

    While ActiveSheet.Range("A" & f).Value <> "" ' recorro source
    
        If wsLista.Range("N" & fila).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & f).Value Then ' comparo que los valores coincidan
            wsLista.Range("T" & fila).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & f).Value 'actualizo el valor de la columna "T" en la Lista (solo son valores numericos, ningun valor booleano en la columna "D" 
            f = 600 'salgo del bucle
        End If
        f = f + 1
    Wend        
End If
fila = fila + 1
```

Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que lo hace Excel al abrir automáticamente. ¿has probado a abrirlo como archivo de texto? Otra opción es que tu macro modifique esa columna y los pase a valores de texto (por ejemplo, poniendo `'` antes del valor)

Comment: Es precisamente lo que quiero evitar, poner a todas las columnas como formato texto, son muchas columnas y muchas filas, no entiendo porque cuando abro manualmente el archivo csv no se convierte ninguna columna, me respeta los valores que tengo, pero cuando ejecuto la macro si los convierte

Comment: Pon el código a ver.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes listo agregue el código es muy simple

Comment: @Rchrd no puedes definirlo directamente como workbook al abrirlo, pero prueba con `OpenText` en lugar de `Open` a secas. Por otro lado, quizá utilizando el parámetro `Local:=False` al abrir el libro te ayude a que no lo convierta.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es trabajar con archivos CSV desde VBA, prueba [esta solución](https://github.com/ws-garcia/VBA-CSV-interface). Con VBA CSV interface puedes:

- Importar ficheros CSV filtrando filas y columnas.
- Escribir los datos directamente a una hoja de Excel.
- Cambiar el tipo de datos de cada campo importado.
- Ordenar los datos importados antes de escribirlos en la hoja de Excel.

¡Suerte!